# neo4j : k-shortest path Built-In Algorithm support

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I need to find k-shortest paths between two nodes in neo4j.

Options tried till now:

I found Built-in Algorithm support for Djikstra,A* using shortestpath, allshortestpath calls as well as APOC procedures but none which suits my need.

- All these give "one/many shortest path of lease weight/length of
  paths" and not best k shortest path
- Giving Depth in the relation [:CONNECTED_TO*1..n] does not help either

I have gone through the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637194/neo4j-k-shortest-paths-with-cost-property)

Also found this plugin https://github.com/Caleydo/neo4j-kshortestpaths-plugin But cannot figure out how to use it. I am able to successfully add it to neo4j plugins

Any pointers welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to run this plugin https://github.com/Caleydo/neo4j-kshortestpaths-plugin and it gives the correct result as well.

How to Use:

- Build the package using MVN against **correct neo4j version** that
  you are using. Update the POM file with the neo4j version before
  building
- You need to pass **node URI** and not node/nodeID as parameter for
  source and target. (I was stuck here in this step)